# Simple Bash Script says Command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command

I'm trying to run an extremely simple bash script that runs some commands on the shell. For now, all it is composed of is:

```
#!/bin/bash

eos
```

Where "eos" is a perfectly legit command that runs perfectly fine on the server I'm using if I run it manually on the same shell.

However, when I chmod +x and execute this script, I get the error:

```
./cp.sh: line 21: eos: command not found
```

Does anyone have any idea why it won't submit these commands?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't `eos` just an alias?

Comment: Try `type eos` to find out what `eos` really is.

Comment: You guys are right! I didn't even think about eos being an alias (nor did I know you couldn't use aliases in bash scripts.) anyway I just typed out the entire alias and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What user is running the script? I suspect an environment or pwd issue, although permissions are a possibility.
Try using the full path to eos or setup the necessary environment in the script.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about eos being an alias (nor did I know you couldn't use aliases in bash scripts.) anyway I just typed out the entire alias and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In unix shell "command not found" error comes when the directory at which command is located is not in PATH (an env variable) which is searched to locate the command.

The solution to this is either of any of the 2 approaches mentioned below

a) change PATH and export PATH variable either in shell startup files or user profiles

```
export PATH=$PATH:/eos-command-directory-location/
```

b) run the eos command in shell script you have developed with full path

Comment: 1. You don't need to export the `PATH` variable (it's very likely already marked as exported). 2. You have a typo in your assignment: paths are colon-separated. 3. You need to quote the expansion of the `PATH` variable. 4. Did you read that OP's problem is solved and did you notice that the problem he had isn't mentioned in your answer? (so your claim _the solution to this is either of any of the 2 approaches mentioned below_ is not true).